# Как получить имя файла используя регулярное выражение?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator, path, qregexp

Есть путь к файлу ,например такой "D:/QT projects/ConnectDB/Vlad.jpg",как при помощи регулярного выражения получить Vlad.jpg?

Comment: Для этого не нужно регулярное выражение, достаточно функций strrchr и substr или их аналогов

Comment: что-то в qt не получается найти substr

Comment: Я бы сильно удивился, если бы ничего аналогичного там не было...

Comment: Я не нашел,к сожалению(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по всему, сработает такое:

```
QString fileName = QFileInfo("D:/QT projects/ConnectDB/Vlad.jpg").fileName();
```

Документация: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html#fileName

Answer (score 0):

Вот извращенный :) способ, заодно знакомящий с алгоритмами STL

```
const char sz [] =  "dir1\\dir2\\dir3\\dir4\\name.ext";
std::cout << std::find (std::reverse_iterator <const char *> (sz + strlen (sz)),
                        std::reverse_iterator <const char *> (sz), '\\').base ();
```

Если использовать std::string, то все попроще.
Пример для Винды, у Вас, видимо, слеш другой, замените на поиск '/'.